# Quartz.Net file store

Tags: quartz.net-2.0

Quartz.Net provides RAMJobStore and AdoJobStore to store the internal state in volatile memory and a database respectively.

It also effectively allows persisting some state in a file by watching an XML file.

But there is no FileJobStore, which would store the same information as AdoJobStore in case there is a system reboot. This is the obvious solution to small-scale schedules to be protected against a system reboot. Why?

I can think of efficiency considerations. But the advantage would be setting up a persistence instance of Quartz.Net without any dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and up-voted you but I could not find any answer and turned to [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/) at last. It's a file-based embedded database which solved my requirements. You can have a try, if you still needs it.